# Yii2 JQuery post request fails, bad request

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

I'm new to PHP and Yii2 but I'm working on a project where a user can change the language of the site by clicking on the language option.

I did a post request in jquery

```
        $(document).on('click','.language',function() {
            var lang = JSON.stringify($(".language").attr('id'));
            console.log("This is lang:" +lang)

            $.post('language',{'lang':lang}, function(data) {
                console.log("Hello")
                location.reload();
                console.log("Hello2")
            });
        });
}
```

and the function in the site controller

```
public function actionLanguage()
    {
        console.log("ActionLanguage");
        if(isset($_POST['lang'])){
            Yii::$app->language = $_POST['lang'];
            console.log('cookie');
            $cookie = new yii\web\Cookie([
                'name'=>'lang',
                'value'=>$_POST['lang']
            ]);
            Yii::$app->getResponse()->getCookies()->add($cookie);   
        }
    }
```

However when I click on an option to change the language, I get a 400 error

```
POST http://localhost:8080/site/language 400 (Bad Request)
```

It says bad request but I don't know where exactly. Could someone please help?

Comment: You need to pass csrf token with post request.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `console.log("ActionLanguage");` and `console.log('cookie');` in action method (which is written in PHP) won't work.

Comment: @MichalHynčica I used those just to check my functions. Its JQuery, it works on the console

Comment: But in code you've posted you have them inside of `public function actionLanguage()`. That's clearly not JQuery there. It's not cause of the Bad Request that's because of missing CSRF token as Insane Skull said. But, if you really have them in your code it will cause another error once you fix the missing CSRF token.

Comment: @MichalHynčica yeah! Missed that thanks.